# Eclipse (STS) with m2eclipse - not showing compile errors in Problems view

Tags: eclipse, m2eclipse

This is maybe silly question, but I will try to ask anyway :).

**It is possible to link compile errors form Maven Console to Eclipse Problems Window ?**

I can see errors in the maven console, but the Eclipse Problems view showing no errors, only warnings.

I'm using Spring Source Tool Suite (STS) with M2Eclipse plugin. 
My Maven project (for example CarService) consists of 2 modules (server, client). Each of them is separate eclipse project and I don't have imported the parent pom, only the child poms.
Problems window is configured to show all possible errors :).

Thank you for any advice :).

Comment: I have a similar problem with RAD.  It's definitely a limitation

Comment: check out this question [Eclipse Problems View not showing Errors anymore](http://stackoverflow.com/q/253357/16487).  The source folder answer seems to have worked for me.  Let me know if you want that as an answer.