# Eclipse creating "Javadoc: [identifier] cannot be resolved or is not a field" warnings unnecessarily

Tags: java, eclipse

Eclipse seems to be generating a lot of these unnecessary warnings about JavaDoc in my code, and I can't seem to be able to get rid of the warnings.

First of all, the warnings don't make sense. These appear in links, like:

```java
/**
 * {@link Foo#bar}
 */
```

Where `Foo.bar` definitely exists. Eclipse can find it via right click > open declaration. The field is `protected`.

At first, I thought it was because `Foo` inherits from another class, which is where `bar` actually belongs, but changing the link to the super class doesn't remove the warning.

All the warnings are for the same field. I've tried accessing it in different ways (including `Foo#bar`, `SuperClass#bar`, `#bar`, and the fully qualified name).

I used to have enabled JavaDoc warnings in Java > Compiler > Javadoc, but have since disabled them. The project settings are also disabled.

The code base is using Java 8, which changed how Javadoc warnings and errors work, so it may be related to this (the JavaDoc can't be created by Eclipse because of errors in the Javadoc, presumably caused by Java 8, but we only use Eclipse's JavaDoc on hover, anyway).

I have two pieces of additional software installed in Eclipse: m2e v1.5 and CodePro v7.1.

`mvn compile` has no warnings, so I'm pretty sure that this is an Eclipse issue. Using Eclipse 4.4. I've tried restarting and rebuilding the project several times.

The warnings only show up in the problems view if I choose Show > Show all. Ticking all the individual "show options" does not display these warnings. They're still displayed in the editor, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out this was a problem with the AJDT, which I had recently removed. The AJDT (at least the dev version for Eclipse 4.4 as of 2014-07-19) does not uninstall cleanly. As a result, the program wasn't building correctly (and in fact, errors could not be detected).

The fix is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9586448/1968462). The issue was that the AJDT left a `buildCommand` and `nature` in the `.project` file, which should have been changed back to `org.eclipse.jdt.core.javabuilder` and `org.eclipse.jdt.core.javanature`, respectfully.